# How to start ubuntu from grub?

Tags: grub2

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 LTS and the last time I launched the update tool I ended up in the grub command prompt (no error message). I waited for a while before shuting it down. Now when i start I end up in the grub command prompt. How do i start ubuntu from here ?

Comment: How long did you wait before closing grub? Grub will run after about 10seconds

Comment: Perhaps useful (or related): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329926/grub-starts-in-command-line-after-reboot

Comment: waited for ~5min

Comment: "Perhaps useful (or related): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329926/grub-starts-in-command-line-after-reboot" solved my problem, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can use your computers 'boot menu', which is different on different computers, to go into all the bootable devices and find the grub that way. For example on my razer blade stealth, i could hit f12, and it would bring up a menu similar to the GRUB, with the grub actually in that list. navigating to the grub option allowed me to go into the grub